# PHP/JQuery: Posting to a PHP Script then returning the values and updating HTML with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm fairly new to PHP and really new to JQuery.

So I writ some JQuery that does some calculations, I writ something below that is similar:

```
//on change of a selectbox with the class item
$('.item').change(function() {
  // set variable id as the id name of this id 
  var id = this.id;
  // price variable is equal to the value of the element id 'hiddenprice'
  price = $("#hiddenprice").val();
  // number of items is the value of the select box
  numberofitems = $(this).val();
  // number of days is equal to a php variable I set on the page
  numofdays = "<?php echo $length->days; ?>";
  //totalprice is equal to the 'price' multiplied by 'numofdays'
  totalprice = Number(price) * Number(numofdays);
  //calculates final total by multiplying the 'totalprice' by 'numofitems'
  finaltotal = Number(totalprice ) * Number(numofitems); 
  //updates the HTML with the new price
  $('#'+id).html("&euro;" + finaltotal.toFixed(2));

});
```

I was trying this and although I got it to work, after reading up some I am aware that because this script is in my footer of the page that is getting updated, it is unsafe and easy to manipulate if a user wanted to be malicious.

So I want to do the calculations server side, by posting values to a PHP script and then returning the values.

```
// POST values to PHP Script

$id = (posted select id);
$price = (#hiddenprice variable value);
$numofitems = (posted value of the select);
$numofdays = $length->days;

$totalprice = (int)$price * (int)$numofdays;
$finaltotal = (int)$totalprice * (int)numofitems;

//Then push $finaltotal and $id back to the user viewed page

$('#'+<?php echo $id; ?>).html("&euro;" + <?php echo $finaltotal; ?>.toFixed(2));
```

I'm just not sure how to push them to the page without refresh and then return them, also without refresh.

Again, sorry if this is simple, I have looked at JQuery form plugins, I just wondered if there is more apt solution for what I would like to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it can post or get data without refreshing the page. Also the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105211/jquery-ajax-post-to-php) may be helpful too.

Comment: I used ajax like you said in JQuery and then echo'd out a variable

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX. This sends data to the server and allows you to execute a callback once you receive a response.

If you are using jQuery, then read up about the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method.

To handle the response, the easiest data type to use is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

So a quick example

**Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    url: calculation_url.php,
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: {price: price, days: numofdays },
    success: function(response) {
        // you should check a valid response was received
        $("#result").html(response.html);
    }
});
```

**PHP** - calculatin_url.php

```
$price = $_POST['price'];
$days = $_POST['days'];
// do calculations

// send data back as json
die(json_encode(array('html' => $finalTotal)));
```

To start this process you will need to attach events to the calculation button. Read about registering events with the [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method and you may find it helpful to read about the [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) method.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see this or I would of accepted it as the answer, must of accepted just as I accepted.