# How can i output Ajax Value to a PHP Variable?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Problem :

1. There is a Value1 that is calculated from Ajax Function `addToAuthorizeform()`;
2. There is a Value2 that is a PHP varibale `$amount`. This variable should show the output of the `value1` that is calculated by Ajax Function.
3. How it is possible?

My code so far:

```
//AJAX FUNCTION THAT OUTPUTS AN AMOUNT 
//SEE LINE 24 value="'+arrData[1]+'" <-- This is the correct value that needs to be //output on PHP VARIABLE

<script>
    function addToAuthorizeForm() {
        $wbc('#slots_purchased').html('');
        var new_html = '';
        var i = 1;
        $wbc('#booking_slots').find('input').each(function () {
            if ($wbc(this).attr('checked')) {
                var slot_id = $wbc(this).val();
                //ajax request to get data
                $wbc.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo plugins_url('
                    my_plugin / public ');?>/ajax/getSlotInfo.php?slot_id=' + $wbc(this).val(),
                    success: function (data) {

                        arrData = data.split("$");
                        if (arrData[1] > 0) {
                            q = 1;
                            if ($wbc('#seats_' + slot_id).val() != undefined) {
                                q = $wbc('#seats_' + slot_id).val();
                            }
                            new_html += '<input type="hidden" name="x_amount_' + i + '" value="' + arrData[1] + '" />';
                            $wbc('#slots_purchased').html(new_html);
                            i++;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }

        });

    }
</script>
```

Now The PHP Variable is

```
$amount = '';
```

Now I need to know what code should I put after `$amount = 1` so I can call or echo the Ajax same value `'+arrData[1]+'` that is calculated on line 24 of the Javascript Function.

**Here is the Authorize.net HTML form that i am using to Submit.**

```
<?php
require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; // Include the SDK you downloaded in Step 2
$fname = $bookingReservationObj->getReservationName();
$api_login_id = $bookingSettingObj->getAuthorizeAPI();
$transaction_key =  $bookingSettingObj->getAuthorizeTXN();
$amount = // I am not sure what to put here to call Ajax value that i need answer
$fp_timestamp = time();
$fp_sequence = "123" . time(); // Enter an invoice or other unique number.
$fingerprint = AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login_id,
  $transaction_key, $amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp)
?>

    <!-- authorize.net form -->
    <form action='https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll' METHOD='POST' name="authorize_form" style="display:inline">

        <!-- Authorize Configuration -->

        <input type='hidden' name="x_login" value="<?php echo $api_login_id ?>" />
        <input type='hidden' name="x_fp_hash" value="<?php echo $fingerprint?>" />
        <input type='hidden' name="x_fp_timestamp" value="<?php echo $fp_timestamp?>" />
        <input type='hidden' name="x_fp_sequence" value="<?php echo $fp_sequence?>" />
        <input type='hidden' name="x_version" value="3.1">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_show_form" value="payment_form">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_test_request" value="true" />
        <input type='hidden' name="x_method" value="cc">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_first_name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_last_name" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_email" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_phone" value="<?php echo $fname ?>">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_description" value="<?php echo 'Cruzz Booking '; ?>">


       <!--slots purchased-->
        <div id="slots_purchased">

        </div>

        <input type='hidden' name="x_receipt_link_method" value="link">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_receipt_link_text" value="Click here to return to our home page">
        <input type='hidden' name="x_receipt_link_URL" value="<?php echo site_url('')."/?p=".$post->ID."&authorize_confirm=1"; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name=" x_cancel_url" value="<?php echo site_url('')."/?p=".$post->ID; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="POST">



    </form>
```

How should I start?

Comment: how you get anything when you have empty string in $amount ...

Comment: what are you doing with that $amount variable?

Comment: i dont know what to write after $amount so i can get the value of Ajax call, this is why i am asking, Thanks

Comment: But if the page is already loaded, you can't assign a variable, so my question is this again.....what are you wanting to do with that $amount variable

Comment: @Kylek $amount variable is Authorize.net amount, it is required because Authorize.net uses this variable output to calculate fingerprint.

Comment: ok, so when is it used? before or after your ajax? On next page? when?

Comment: What I mean, is youre either gonna have to hide it in the DOM or store as a cookie, to be able to use it on the next page.....but the real question remains....when is $amount used?  I guess what Im trying to say is, if you need it on THIS page, you're out of luck, you can't assign php variable after the request has already been made.....the only option then, if you need it on this page, is to assign it to javascript, and then do your Authorize through ajax as well

Comment: Show PHP code with `$amount`.

Comment: $amount is used when the button is pressed.

Comment: AJAX runs on the client, PHP runs on the server. You can't set server variables from the client, except by performing another AJAX call.

Comment: @Barmar how can i perform another Ajax call, can you please help. Kylek i have to echo $amount such as <?php echo $amount ?> so form can be processed but i need $amount = value calculated from Ajax function in my question

Comment: It's not clear what you're really trying to do. You're already putting the amount into the form with Javascript, why do you think you need to do it with PHP? PHP can only output whole pages, it can't update parts of the existing page, you do that with Javascript.

Comment: Well if the variable is already there i your ajax you have it....you don't need $amount to insert into form....infact you are already inserting it into the input already....unless you need it in another field, then thats easy, just provide the html of the field you need to put it in, and Ill give you code

Comment: Are you gonna give me the element you wanna insert it into or not???

Comment: ok let me make it clear again, If i dont use $amount, i can not accompish the form to submit to Authorize.net Payment gateway, that receive the amount from $amount variable, If you check the code above, You will see new_html is what submit the value calculated from Ajax. I need to output this value using PHP variable $amount. Thanks

Comment: God probably just abandonned us...

Comment: I understand what youre trying to do, but you dont need to give it to $amount......if you need it in your form, to submit to the other side....you ALREADY HAVE IT from that ajax call.....so lets use it.......in fact unless you provide WHERE that $amount is being used, nobody can help you

Comment: @Kylek i updated the HTML form that is being output

Comment: @Kylek if i dont use $amount variable, $fingerprint will not be generated and it returns error. thats the case. If you know any other method please help

Comment: Does  AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login_id,
  $transaction_key, $amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp)  rely on the $amount?

Comment: @Kylek Yes you can see that on code. that is why i want to assign ajax value to $amount

Comment: Ok, well the answer is you can't....but I have a feeling you're doing something backwards here

Comment: Why are you using ajax for the amount in the first place? Can this not be calculated on the server?

Comment: @Kylek because the user have to select number of Quantities before he submit form, and the best method to calculate this is Ajax only

Comment: Well the only solution I see, is that when you do that ajax call to get the amount, at that point you move that  AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login_id, $transaction_key, $amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp)   into that page, and return both the amount and figerprint at the same time

Comment: But you will have to pass, the $api, $transaction_key, $fp_sequence, and timestamp to the ajax as well....its a complete restructuring on the other side for you

Comment: i am getting your point @Kylek but can you write the code and show example please

Comment: No unfortunately not, this is a complex job.....I can do it for you, but I charge $50/hr, which I doubt you feel like paying, for something that you can probably figure out with time

Comment: I would need to see all the other code, for example...the code for plugins_url('my_plugin / public ');?>/ajax/getSlotInfo.php?

Comment: thank you for help, your doubt is true, Not able to pay. Thanks again

Comment: No problem.  Hopefully you get what Im trying to say....when I say, put that Authorize function on the other side, in the getSlotInfo.php file, and in your ajax, you will pass those other variables

Answer (score 0):

In your code `$wbc` must be your jQuery Object, it's normally just `$`. If for some reason `$wbc` does not refer to the jQuery Object you have a problem. `ajax` is a method of the jQuery Object. The `ajax` method takes an Object Literal as its argument. A JavaScript Object Literal is really an Associative Array. `url` is a property of the Object You are passing in as an argument. The value for that property is `'<?php echo plugins_url('my_plugin/public');?>/ajax/getSlotInfo.php?slot_id='+ $wbc(this).val()`, which you must be running through your server, so this must be a `.php` file. To use `plugins_url()` you must be using WordPress.

You are using the `$wbc.ajax({type:'GET'})` method so additional information can be sent like `'getSlotInfo.php?slot_id='+$wbc(this).val()+'&anotherProperty=anotherValue`. So the `&` seperates properties.

See where your code says `getSlotInfo.php?slot_id=`? The `slot_id` part can be accessed with `$_GET['slot_id']` on the page your `url` is sending information to, which happens to be `getSlotInfo.php`. You can use `<?php $varHere = $_GET['slot_id'] ?>` on your `getSlotInfo.php` page to create a PHP variable that holds jQuery.

If you had a `dataType: 'json'` in your `ajax` method Object argument, like `$wbc.ajax({dataType: 'json'})`, then you could use PHP to generate JavaScript Object Notation, which is an Associative Array. The PHP method of choice for this on your `getSlotInfo.php` page will be `json_encode()`. As long as you `print` or `echo json_encode()` with PHP, when you have a successful response the `data` argument of `$wbc.ajax({success: function(data){}})` will hold the Associative Array, which can be used with JavaScript's for in loop like:

```
for(var i in data){
  var property = i;
  var value = data[i];
}
```

Your PHP, on `getSlotInfo.php`, that sends to this JavaScript Object Literal might look like:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['slot_id']) && isset($_GET['anotherProperty'])){
    $ary = array('prop1' => $_GET['slot_id'], 'prop2' => $_GET['anotherProperty']);
    echo json_encode($ary);
  }
  else{
    header('LOCATION: urlOfChoice.html');
  }
?>
```

Using this methodology there is no reason to `split` the `data` since its not a string response. Instead it's already `JSON`.

This might help you understand the `post` method [Jquery AJAX post to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105211/jquery-ajax-post-to-php).

Comment: im not sure how to do this